# While loading image from galleryActivity has leaked window that was originally added here?

Tags: android

When  I  upload image from gallery in application but when i selected some images i got this exception.

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity  has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4133c7d8 that was originally added here

android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(Win
```

dowManagerImpl.java:152)
I didn;t why i got exception randomly??

this code is for open gallery..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setType("image/*");
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

below code is for getting bimap from gallery
 i

```
f (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) 
                   {

                        Uri contentUri = data.getData();
                        System.out.println("**************contentUri***************"+contentUri);
                        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        String tmppath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                        // File abc= new File(tmppath);
                        System.out.println("**************tmppath***************"+tmppath);

                        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmppath); 
                       // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(abc);
                        System.out.println("**************mBitmap(gallery)***************"+mBitmap);
                        Court_formations  objectdat =new Court_formations();
                        objectdat.showGalleryimage(getDialogContext(),mBitmap);
```

plz help

Comment: When i open gallery in horizonall mode then back to application as it fixed in potrait mode then i got this exception

Comment: are you just picking a image from galery and showing it on imageview?

Comment: and what is Court_formations?

Comment: It is class from where  i open dialogbox ..

Comment: I fixed my application mode it is potrait and when i change device orientation in horizontal and i back to application which is in potrait mode then i got this exception

Comment: does that dialog contains imageview to show image?

Answer (score 1):

in onactivity result try using these code:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(data.getDataString());
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream in = null;
try {
in = cr.openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize=20;
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
Court_formations  objectdat =new Court_formations();
objectdat.showGalleryimage(getDialogContext(),mBitmap);
```

Comment: if the above wont solve your issue then add these for your activity in manifest file.. android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"